# Show commits and description but hide code in repository [Github]

Tags: github

I've almost done my first big project in React+Typescript+Redux and started it on Firebase with users and some database conneted with logged users.

It was supposed to be my project to portfolio before looking for my first dev job, but it start to be very complex.
Now I have idea to use it in the future to make commercial app.
So the problem is I don't want to publish my code on github, but at the same time I want to publish all my commits and repository description on Github for recrutiers (and all my tasks from trello table). Is it possible to publish only commits and description from github repository?

Comment: I doubt you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  If your repository is public, anyone can clone the entire repository.  The only way to make your code inaccessible is to make the repository private, which means nobody can see it without having permssion.